# What are the return object requirements for an AWS websocket $connect path of the Gateway V2 API

Tags: amazon-web-services, websocket, aws-api-gateway, terraform-provider-aws, lambda-authorizer

I am using terraform to create a websocket with their AWS gatewayv2 resources, such as **aws_apigatewayv2_route** and **aws_apigatewayv2_authorizer**.

When my authorizer lambda runs, it gets a token from the incoming `"type": "REQUEST"` event, via headers.Auth, which looks like "Bearer eyJmaWOiQiI3Y...JTMjU2In0.eyJxpWIiOi..." (a very long string).  The token is the part after "Bearer ".

The code processes the token to get the 'kid' and so forth, and matches it against the keys retrieved from the cognito jwks.json file (it is sample code that I got from the AWS website somewhere).

The code flows thru to the **'Signature successfully verified'** point -- great so far!

**The problem is:** what should the authorizer lambda return?

The sample code that successfully verifies the signature indicates that a claims object should be returned. Which looks like this:

```
claims:
{
    "sub": "2jjtzzzyyyxxx888g2pppp8sqqqqjagn",
    "token_use": "access",
    "scope": "transactions/post",
    "auth_time": 1596108906,
    "iss": "https://cognito-idp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/us-east-1_tZfQltfya",
    "exp": 1596112506,
    "iat": 1596108906,
    "version": 2,
    "jti": "f55a0c1d-b9ac-3b2f-b8da-0ee93335c828",
    "client_id": "2ku7unsnkde8g1i9n8s2usjbgo"
}
```

Other sample code indicates that an authReponse should be returned, which looks like this:

```
authResponse: 
{
    "principalId": "xxxyyyzzz", // <--- I have tried various things here.
    "policyDocument": {
        "Version": "2012-10-17",
        "Statement": [
            {
                "Action": "execute-api:Invoke",
                "Effect": "Allow",
                "Resource": [
                    "arn:aws:execute-api:us-east-1:11122223334444:n10gr0cw7m/test-stage/POST/*"
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Some values have been changed to protect the innocent :-)

I have tried many things, but my wscat cli command that initiates the request gets either `Unexpected server response: 403` or `Unexpected server response: 500` -- depending on what variations I try.

I have also tried returning a simple `{ "statusCode": 200 }` object -- which also does not work.

Answer (score 1):

A Gateway API **V2** authorizer lambda should return a policy response, but with a few fixes.

Here is a working example with comments (also again, with some values changed for security):

```
{
  // "App client ID" from the App integration section of Cognito
  "principalId": "7p9f415hnxxbfbch17jnaenccs", 
  "policyDocument": {
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
      {
        "Action": [  // <--- this must be an array (a V2 change!)
          "execute-api:Invoke"
        ],
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Resource": [
          "arn:aws:execute-api:us-east-1:111222233444:1c9kv22z8g/stage-dev/$connect"
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  "context": null, // <-- optional values to pass to the route integration
  "usageIdentifierKey": null
}
```